# How to hide/show parent elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jquery filter that filters elements containing the string in the `input#box` hiding them.
I've added the initial letters to the HTML and I want to hide them when all contained element are hidden.
I've tried several combination of jQuery `parents`and `closest` without any success...

```js
$('#box').keyup(function() {
  var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  if (valThis == "") {
    $('.indicazione').show();
  } else {
    $('.indicazione').each(function() {
      var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
      if (text.indexOf(valThis) >= 0) {
        $(this).show();
      } else {
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).parents('.indicazione_wrapper').hide(); /*This Line doesn't work*/
      }
    });
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 mt-5 mb-3">
    <input id="box" type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 mt-3" id="lettera"><strong>A</strong></div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 d-flex indicazione_wrapper">
    <div class="card card-body flex-fill my-3">
      <a class="indicazione" href="#">AAA</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 d-flex indicazione_wrapper">
    <div class="card card-body flex-fill my-3">
      <a class="indicazione" href="#">ABC</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 d-flex indicazione_wrapper">
    <div class="card card-body flex-fill my-3">
      <a class="indicazione" href="#">CDE</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 mt-3" id="lettera"><strong>B</strong></div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 d-flex indicazione_wrapper">
    <div class="card card-body flex-fill my-3">
      <a class="indicazione" href="#">BBB</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 d-flex indicazione_wrapper">
    <div class="card card-body flex-fill my-3">
      <a class="indicazione" href="#">ABC</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 d-flex indicazione_wrapper">
    <div class="card card-body flex-fill my-3">
      <a class="indicazione" href="#">CDE</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.parent()` without the final `s`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works just fine, except that you called `$(this).parents('.indicazione_wrapper').hide()` to hide that element, but then you never showed it again.

I've added the `.indicazione_wrapper` selector this part

```js
if (valThis == "") {
    $('.indicazione, .indicazione_wrapper').show(); 
  } else { ...
```

and then I added some BG color to show that the correct elements are hiding and showing.

```js
$('#box').keyup(function() {
  var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  if (valThis == "") {
    $('.indicazione, .indicazione_wrapper').show(); 
  } else {
    $('.indicazione').each(function() {
      var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
      if (text.indexOf(valThis) >= 0) {
        $(this).show();
      } else {
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).parents('.indicazione_wrapper').hide(); /*This Line doesn't work*/
      }
    });
  };
});
```

```css
.indicazione_wrapper {
  background: lightblue;
}

.indicazione {
  background: pink;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 mt-5 mb-3">
    <input id="box" type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 mt-3" id="lettera"><strong>A</strong></div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 d-flex indicazione_wrapper">
    <div class="card card-body flex-fill my-3">
      <a class="indicazione" href="#">AAA</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 d-flex indicazione_wrapper">
    <div class="card card-body flex-fill my-3">
      <a class="indicazione" href="#">ABC</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 d-flex indicazione_wrapper">
    <div class="card card-body flex-fill my-3">
      <a class="indicazione" href="#">CDE</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 mt-3" id="lettera"><strong>B</strong></div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 d-flex indicazione_wrapper">
    <div class="card card-body flex-fill my-3">
      <a class="indicazione" href="#">BBB</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 d-flex indicazione_wrapper">
    <div class="card card-body flex-fill my-3">
      <a class="indicazione" href="#">ABC</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 d-flex indicazione_wrapper">
    <div class="card card-body flex-fill my-3">
      <a class="indicazione" href="#">CDE</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think the `$(this).hide()` is necessary as you are already hiding the parent div.

Change your code to this:

```js
$('#box').keyup(function() {
  var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
      
  if (valThis == "") {
    $('.indicazione_wrapper').show();
  } else {
    $('.indicazione').each(function() {
      var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
      if (text.indexOf(valThis) >= 0) {
        $(this).show();
      } else {
         $(this).parents('.indicazione_wrapper').hide();
      }
    });
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 mt-5 mb-3">
    <input id="box" type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 mt-3" id="lettera"><strong>A</strong></div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 d-flex indicazione_wrapper">
    <div class="card card-body flex-fill my-3">
      <a class="indicazione" href="#">AAA</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 d-flex indicazione_wrapper">
    <div class="card card-body flex-fill my-3">
      <a class="indicazione" href="#">ABC</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 d-flex indicazione_wrapper">
    <div class="card card-body flex-fill my-3">
      <a class="indicazione" href="#">CDE</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 mt-3" id="lettera"><strong>B</strong></div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 d-flex indicazione_wrapper">
    <div class="card card-body flex-fill my-3">
      <a class="indicazione" href="#">BBB</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 d-flex indicazione_wrapper">
    <div class="card card-body flex-fill my-3">
      <a class="indicazione" href="#">ABC</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 d-flex indicazione_wrapper">
    <div class="card card-body flex-fill my-3">
      <a class="indicazione" href="#">CDE</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ok, that's true, but I need to hide the `div#lettera` and it's not hiding also in your code...

Comment: You didnt mention that in the question, checking on it.

Comment: yes, I did " I've added the initial letters to the HTML and I want to hide them when all contained element are hidden."

Answer (score 0):

You can't hide the inital letters when all contained elements are hidden, because your your initial headers are not containing the elements you are hiding.

Wrap your child elements ("AAA", "ABC") in the div containting your initial letters "A". Then you can select them with the parent() selector.

```
<div class="col-sm-12 mt-3" id="lettera"><strong>A</strong> <!-- REMOVE here-->
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 d-flex indicazione_wrapper">
    <div class="card card-body flex-fill my-3">
      <a class="indicazione" href="#">AAA</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> <!-- ADD here-->
```

Then you can select them using parent()

```
$('.indicazione_wrapper').parent();
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove unnecessary $(this).parents('.indicazione_wrapper').hide(); from `if` and add this code

```
if($(this).closest('.indicazione_wrapper').find('.indicazione:hidden').length ==                            
    $(this).closest('.indicazione_wrapper').find('.indicazione').length) {
        $(this).closest('.indicazione_wrapper').first().hide();
}
```

And you need wrap your items into

```
<div class="indicazione_wrapper"> ... </div>
```

```js
$('#box').keyup(function() {
  var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  if (valThis == "") {
    $('.indicazione').show();
  } else {
    $('.indicazione').each(function() {
    
     $(this).closest('.indicazione_wrapper').first().show(); // <-- show latters after input change
    
      var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
      if (text.indexOf(valThis) >= 0) {
        $(this).show();
      } else {
        $(this).hide();
      }
      
      // hide latter if all items are hidden
      if($(this).closest('.indicazione_wrapper').find('.indicazione:hidden').length ==              $(this).closest('.indicazione_wrapper').find('.indicazione').length) {
       $(this).closest('.indicazione_wrapper').first().hide();
      }
    
    });
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 mt-5 mb-3">
    <input id="box" type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="indicazione_wrapper">
    <div class="col-sm-12 mt-3" id="lettera"><strong>A</strong></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 d-flex ">
      <div class="card card-body flex-fill my-3">
        <a class="indicazione" href="#">AAA</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 d-flex">
      <div class="card card-body flex-fill my-3">
        <a class="indicazione" href="#">ABC</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 d-flex">
      <div class="card card-body flex-fill my-3">
        <a class="indicazione" href="#">CDE</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="indicazione_wrapper">
    <div class="col-sm-12 mt-3" id="lettera"><strong>B</strong></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 d-flex">
      <div class="card card-body flex-fill my-3">
        <a class="indicazione" href="#">BBB</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 d-flex">
      <div class="card card-body flex-fill my-3">
        <a class="indicazione" href="#">AX</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 d-flex">
      <div class="card card-body flex-fill my-3">
        <a class="indicazione" href="#">CDE</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>     
</div>
```